# Using element_markdown() from ggtext to place two captions in a ggplot figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

I am trying to create a `ggplot2` figure with two captions, one left-aligned and one right-aligned. This works properly when using `element_text()` in `theme()` to format the figures.

```
  ggplot(mtcars) + 
  aes(x=cyl, y=disp) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(caption=c("First caption here","Second caption here")) + 
  theme(plot.caption=element_text(hjust=c(0,1)))
```

[image: Figure created using element_text()]

When I attempt to replicate this with `element_markdown()` from the `ggtext` package instead of `element_text()`, it does not place the captions properly.

```
  ggplot(mtcars) + 
  aes(x=cyl, y=disp) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(caption=c("First caption here","Second caption here")) + 
  theme(plot.caption=element_markdown(hjust=c(0,1)))
```

[image: Figure created using element_markdown()]

Ideally, I'd like to use `element_markdown()` because it would allow more formatting options in the captions (bolding text, including images, etc). I'd greatly appreciate any advice on how to troubleshoot this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure why this is not working the same way but you could simply change the hjust to a more extreme value. It will be harder to get exactly right but should work.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  aes(x=cyl, y=disp) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(caption=c("First caption here","Second caption here")) + 
  theme(plot.caption=element_markdown(hjust=c(0, -5)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is a really helpful workaround. In the long run, it'd be ideal to use 0 and 1 values for hjust so that the code can be used for various image sizes, but this is very helpful in the present.